# Codeigniter URL rewriting not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I'm using the following .htaccess file to rewrite the URL's without index.php:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The site is uploaded on my VPS, and when I enter it on, let's say:

```
http://1.1.1.1/~admin/
```

it works fine. Now when I want to navigate through the website to for instance:

```
http://1.1.1.1/~admin/welcome
```

it gives me the following error message:

```
The requested URL /home/admin/public_html/index.php/welcome was not found on this server.
```

Now when I access the welcome controller with the index.php in the URL:

```
http://1.1.1.1/~admin/index.php/welcome
```

It works fine again. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

The "?" after index.php is required for godaddy. See this link: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installation-Tips

Answer (score 0):

The path /welcome does not exist on the server, the rewrite should be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: the rewrite should produce a correct path by converting the welcome to a parameter, /home/admin/public_html/index.php?var1=welcome

Comment: It doesn't. It gives me this message: The requested URL /home/admin/public_html/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: @Daan No, OP doesn't want URL parameters, nor it should normally (as CI defaults to url segments). The rewrite looks fine, what server are you running on?

Comment: A VPS running CentOS 6.4 with DirectAdmin. Mod_rewrite seems to be working fine, I've also checked that AllowOverride All is there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I wrote this: Trouble Shooting Codeigniter on localhost

http://garyjohnson53.wordpress.com/2013/10/31/trouble-shooting-codeigniter-on-localhost/



Its not a polished article, but it walks you through a few of the common things with codeigniter.

MVC URI segments
example.com/class/method/id/

your condif.php usually in application/config
your index.php
your .htacess
Alias and apache
```

etc.